# Can state secrets be revealed in a criminal lawsuit?

Tags: criminal-law, secret

Imagine if there is criminal lawsuit against a CIA agent before a U.S. court. To defend himself, he needs to reveal secrets. For example, he would need to reveal other CIA agents whose lives would be threatened if their names become public.

He has the option to remain silent, but if he did so he would not be able to defend himself.

What is the protocol in such a case? Is he allowed to reveal that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [state secrets doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_secrets_privilege#:%7E:text=%22The%20state%20secrets%20privilege%20is,security.%22%20%E2%80%93%20Zuckerbraun%20v.) that as a practical matter prohibits the litigation is issues in which state secrets figure in the case in a civilian court that is open to the public by dismissing the case.

"The state secrets privilege is a common law evidentiary rule that allows the government to withhold information from discovery when disclosure would be inimical to national security." *Zuckerbraun v. General Dynamics Corp.*, 935 F.2d 544, 546 (2d Cir. 1991).

It was recognized as a common law privilege in *United States v. Reynolds*, 345 U.S. 1, 7 (1953), and is usually invoked in civil lawsuits, but is not inherently so limited.

Of course, the federal government has the authority to waive the privilege in order to allow a criminal prosecution to go forward.

Among other things this doctrine means that covert operatives are not allowed to bring lawsuits for unpaid compensation against the government, even if they have a solid case on the merits.